# How should I interpret MDD and ASD?

Tags: hedge-fund

I'm studying hedge funds and I'm looking at two figures that I'm not sure how to interpret:

The first is Max Drawdown, which I see scaling from 0 to -30ish.

Is Fund A with a MDD of -15 more or less volatile than Fund B with a MDD of -30?

The second is Annualized Standard Deviation, which I see scaling from 0 to 400ish.

Is Fund A with a ASD of 40 more or less volatile than Fund B with a ASD of 350?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the first question: Typically a higher drawdown = more volatile but not all the time. For example, Fund B can have a high watermark of 30% return but end the period at 0% return & therefore have a MDD of -30%. Fund A can have a high watermark of ; 30% return ,but end the period at 15% return therefore have a MDD of -15%. Over this period, Fund B is more volatile since it went from +30% to 0. To answer the second question: in finance standard deviation will most typically = risk. A higher SD is more risky as a return will fluctuate more from its average. Therefore Fund B is more volatile/risky.